# DateFormat default mask

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

In either CF 10 or CF 11 is there a way to change the default mask used by the `DateFormat()` function? The Adobe docs indicate the default is `"dd-mmm-yyyy"` but I haven't seen anything about whether that default can be changed or not. I'm hoping there is an Application setting somewhere to change it.

Comment: Why would you want to change the default? What is the use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also use `long`, `short`, and `medium` for different, easy to type, defaults.

`#dateFormat(date, "short")#`

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff4.html

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to specify your own default. A default kinda is... you know a *default*.

What you could possibly to is set the mask you want in some sort of application-scoped variable (or encompass it all in a date format service or something), which holds what you want to use for a "default" for your specific situation. Then use that as the mask argument when calling `dateFormat()`.

Comment: Or write your own date format function, with a different name.